# magento footer issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, footer

i am working with the magento(1.9.0.1),unfortunately i got the following text in footer are
the text is 
 "text [profiler] Memory usage: real: 18087936, emalloc: 17499024"
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the profiler is for aiding in diagnosing slow page load times.
This should never be left enabled on a deployed website.But sometime we forgot to disable There are actually two aspects of disabling it:

> 1. Turning off profiling under System (menu) -> Configuration (menu item) -> Developer (tab on left) -> Debug (accordion section) -> Profiler(change Yes TO No)
> 2. Make sure all calls to Varien_Profiler::enable(); are commented out in your index.php file.

Hope This will Help You

Comment: at least you have to add some your words.
just copied and paste from here. http://www.magentotutorials.in/magentotutorials/magento-showing-memory-usage-at-the-bottom-of-footer/

Comment: i know the answer a week before . i had a same problem and i clarify my problem here. so i helped this guy.

Comment: but you should have to give your own thoughts not just copied and paste solution from tutorial website. :(

Answer (score 3):

you can disable pro filer from admin

Go to **System ->> Configuration**

```
Click on "Developer" in the left side menu pane
Open the "Debug" section
Change the "Profiler" to "NO"
```

see image

[image]

Also check in your main index.php

`Varien_Profiler::enable();` must be commented